# Remove zeros from Order

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento-2.1.7

I want to remove the four extra padded zeros from the Order id, i.e, Order Id from **000000001** to **00001**

Comment: This blog might help you - https://www.classyllama.com/blog/m2-incrementid

Comment: Please see https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-change-magento-2-orders-increment-id-pad-length/ this will allow you to change the overall length of the incremental id

Answer (score 0):

In `eav_entity_type` table,By default increment id length is 8. So Order Id has 8 0s.

You need to change the length value in `eav_entity_type` table.

First run this query
`SELECT * FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_id =5;`
entity_type_id 5 mentions sales/order.

By default `increment_pad_length` value is 8,you need to change it from 8 to 4 for your need.

change `increment_pad_length` value by run this query

`UPDATE eav_entity_type SET increment_pad_length = 4 WHERE entity_type_id =5;`

I think it will help you..

Comment: Let me know if it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic module and put this in the di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.05d%s</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

The 5 in the argument is the length of the number + padding 0s, ie 00001